# Searching for a certain word and modifying them within Sublime Text 2 and Vim

Tags: vim, text-editors, key-binding, sublime-text-2

I am trying learn the keybindings of vim one by one. I thing that I thought I should get good at early is to find a string of text and replace them with something else.

I had successfully done this on E-TextEditor on Windows where I will key in v/something/\rsomethingelse

for the desired effect.

but I find that isn't the case in the commmand mode in SublimeText 2. What happens in ST2 is that once I am in command mode, I press v which puts the editor in visual mode, then if I key in /, it enters search, then I key in the word "something", if I press "/", it will be part of the search query instead of ending the regexp, okay, I thought, then i press return to see if an instance of something gets selected, but it doesn't, nor does esc or any other key I can think of. Note that the instances of "something" do get found but just not selected for further operations.

Does this feature not exist in SublimeText2 or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you give an example of a "string of text" ... that is an awfully wide term, considering.

Comment: @Idigas for example: say if I want to change the string inside the print function print('awfullyWide') to print('notReally')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nik, either you learn Vim or you learn Sublime Text 2.

ST2's vintage mode is at best a good approximation of Vim's most basic features **within** the constraints of Sublime Text.

For example, it doesn't have the same command line and thus doesn't provide Vim's awesome search/replace feature.

For that you must use ST2's own search/replace mechanism accessible by typing `Ctrl`+`h`.

When you type `/` in "command mode" you have the search bar showing at the bottom of the window. Since it's ST2's own search bar (also accessible via `Ctrl`+`f`) it doesn't work at all like the replace bar. Much less like Vim's command line.

The list of vintage mode/vim similarities is a thousands time shorter than the list of their differences so I suggest you pause and think about what you actually want to do:

`a)` learn how to use Sublime Text 2 which is a very fine text editor

or

`b)` learn how to use Vim which is one of the two best text editors out there (how diplomatic I am).

If you choose `a)` you don't need to activate the vintage mode at all since most of its features are 1/1 mappings to ST2's own features. Stop looking at Vim articles, instead invest your time in learning how ST2 works and how to make the best out of it.

If you choose `b)` the first step **must** be to do the vim tutorial accessible via Terminal.app: type `vimtutor` and follow along. Once you have done `vimtutor` (maybe a couple of times) you can download a recent build of MacVim and start applying your newfound knowledge.

Not making this choice won't lead you anywhere because most of what you will find about Vim won't work in ST2 and what works there is a tiny little fraction of what makes Vim so amazing.

In the end, your choice is irrelevant. What counts is that you make it and focus.

Comment: THANKS! You're going to find his dumb: There's a vimtutor thing?!?! -- Yeah I heard of the MacVim from Peepcode's video ( in fact, for some reason, I have this feeling that there are many flavors of vim ever so slightly different from each other in existence) --- You couldn't be more right about the focus and texteditor getting out of one's way thing. One small reason that's very specific to me, I think , to use vim, is so that I can be keyboard agnostic,having just moved to mac, I can't live with that keyboard so I thought if from now on I can edit with just a-z0-9 and occasional ctrl.

Comment: Actually there is only one flavor of Vim. It can be compiled with or without a huge number of options and have a lot of exotic settings but you still get Vim. MacVim is just Vim wrapped in a nice native Mac OS X GUI. If you really are enthusiastic for Vim you should drop ST2 and dive into Vim without wasting time and energy juggling with editors.

Answer (score 2):

Nik, although I'm certain your intentions are best, I must say I agree (for the
most part) with @romaini on this.

**Vim** and **Sublime Text 2** (**ST2**) are, although trying to be similar (well, one
trying more than the other) two different editors. I have not used **ST2** much, but
**Vim** I've used quite a bit, and it excels at this kind of thing, so it is well worth
learning. It could take some, yes, but as time goes along and you learn "new
tricks" things start to be "logical" more and more.

**Vim's** "power" comes from several things; ***mappings***, ***operator/movement***
***combinations*** and ***regular expressions***.

For example, if we take your string:

```
print('AwfullyWide')
print('NotReally')
```

You're at the beginning of the first line, and you wish to replace the content within
the apostrophes. By typing `ci'` which stands for `change inside apostrophe` (`change` is
the **operator**, `inside '` is the **movement (text)** upon which the operator will be
executed, you will get `print('')` after which you can replace the text inside.

Vim's way of working in this manner is best thought of if you ask yourself "What
do I wish to accomplish with some particular piece of text?". Then it starts
making sense.

Of course, if you wish to do so in one go `:%s/AwfullyWide/NotReally` a simple
substitution will accomplish the same result. Of course, regexes have much more
potential than this simple substitution.

Comment: thanks a million!I thought something might be fishy about the ST2's command mode. Here's why, I actually took the heart to say eff it on windows and switched and thought vim or death. and I bought the peepcode and one other book on it awhile back, and I vaguely remember some commands learned from peepcode's video being different than what's offered but I thought it was just my memory corrupted or something.. now I know for sure. Well that sucks, cuz I kind of like SublimeText's snippets and stuff. I thought, that's VIM with an attractive interface. Thanks though, for such thorough explanation!